# How to order a mongoDB query by a field in an embedded document?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have these documents in a mongoDB:

```
    /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553ce99a39108e2b7c1edeb9"),
    "coleccion" : "aplicaciones",
    "nombre" : "Mascotas",
    "descripcion" : "Censo de mascotas",
    "tipo" : "privada"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553e316e39108e802a1edeb9"),
    "coleccion" : "aplicaciones",
    "nombre" : "otra aplicacionn",
    "descripcion" : "w aplicacion",
    "tipo" : "privada",
    "campoId" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1430145364",
            "id_campo" : "553bffca39108eb163cff7aa",
            "orden" : 90
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1430145368",
            "id_campo" : "553bffed39108e346ccff7ab",
            "orden" : 100,
            "estado" : "0"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1430145370",
            "id_campo" : "553c001139108ebc63cff7aa",
            "orden" : 29,
            "estado" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1430145395",
            "id_campo" : "553c001139108ebc63cff7aa",
            "orden" : 9,
            "estado" : "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to query and sort the data in ascending order of each document using the field " campoId.orden "  and have executed this query:

```
db.getCollection('aplicaciones').find({}).sort({'campoId.orden' : -1})
```

but I do not get the order I want.
can anyone suggest me a way?

Comment: your question in english PLEASE

Comment: sorry
I need to query and sort the data in ascending order of each document using the field " campoid.orden "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your documents `orden` in nested array, so you should use [mongo aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). So below step will follow :

1> First check `campoId` exits or not  [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

2> Then unwind `campoId` array [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

3> Then group all fields [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

So query as below :

```
db.aplicaciones.aggregate({
    "$match": {
      "campoId": {
        "$exists": true // check here campoId presents or not using exists
      }
    }
  }, {
    "$unwind": "$campoId" // unwind campoId array 
  }, {
    "$sort": {
      "campoId.orden": -1
    }
  },
  //groups all fields
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "coleccion": {
        "$first": "$coleccion"
      },
      "nombre": {
        "$first": "$nombre"
      },
      "descripcion": {
        "$first": "$descripcion"
      },
      "tipo": {
        "$first": "$tipo"
      },
      "campoId": {
        "$push": "$campoId"
      }
    }
  }).pretty()
```